# JaxB : Define default @XmlElements for a specific data type

Tags: java, jaxb

As shown below JaxB provides for children to be differentiated by the tag name.

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name="horse", type=Horse.class),
    @XmlElement(name="cow", type=Cow.class)
})
private Animal animal;
```

But how can I implement the desired functionality by default. Every Animal within the document should have the choice of Horse or Cow but I don't want to type the @XmlElements every time ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution is `@XmlSeeAlso`

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html